# Why doesn't rviz appear as a node in rqt_graph?

Tags: ros, rviz, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why doesn't rviz appear as a node in rqt_graph? rviz is subscribed to some topics (such as /scan), but I don't see it in rqt_graph.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269149/why-doesn%27t-rviz-appear-as-a-node-in-rqt_graph?/) by [Cataphract](https://answers.ros.org/users/31427/cataphract/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2017-08-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Cataphract ,

`RViz` is a "debug" node (`rosout` and `rqt_graph` itself also).

When you open `rqt_graph`, I think that by default you have the `Debug` button checked. When this button is checked, all "debug nodes" are hidden.

If you want to show `RViz` on `rqt_graph` you have to "uncheck" the "Debug" button.

The list of nodes that are hidden can be found on a variable called [QUIET_NAMES](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_graph/blob/90117a0b04c99d1baf4589dc97751fa3487883a4/src/rqt_graph/dotcode.py#L52) of rqt_graph.

Looking at the variable, we can see that every node that starts with one of the following values below are hidden when you "check" the Debug button on `rqt_graph`:

```
QUIET_NAMES = ['/diag_agg', '/runtime_logger', '/pr2_dashboard', '/rviz', '/rosout', '/cpu_monitor', '/monitor', '/hd_monitor', '/rxloggerlevel', '/clock', '/rqt', '/statistics']
```

If you prefer watch a video explaining this, I have created a one (https://youtu.be/uVK0Yp4ZDGc) that answers this question and show an example of how to add the `/gazebo` as a Debug Node (for learning purposes), by changing the `QUIET_NAMES` variable.

Cheers,

Ruben.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3